# What is the technical name for declensible languages?

Tags: terminology, linguistic-typology

What is the correct nomenclature for languages constructing logical functions through desinences (through declensions) and what for the ones doing it via prepositions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A language with a certain degree of inflection is called [synthetic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language). The subsets are *highly inflected* and *weakly inflected*.

A *synthetic language* which has derivational morphology so that the complex words become synthesized by concatenation of *unchanged* morphemes is called [agglutinative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutinative_language).
If the bound morphemes serve several roles at once (e.g., person+case or gender+time) and therefore change, that would be a [fusional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusional_language).

In the above cases, the prefixes are not considered separately because usually, all types of affixes serve the common role in the morphology.